# knockout maintaining subscriptions to computed properties even after object is nullified

Tags: knockout.js

Even after I have nullified the objects that have computed properties, the computed properties get called if the dependent observables have changed.

I want that since I have nullified the object it should be garbage collected, but looks like Knockout is keeping the object alive and also the subscriptions which are no longer relevant.

Is there is way in knockout to do this that is remove the subscriptions for the nullified object and hence make it available for garbage collection. I tried to go through its documentation but unsuccessful.

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates the issue..

http://jsfiddle.net/qy4sshv6/5/

```
var Line = function()
{
    this.unit = ko.observable();
    this.convertFactor = ko.observable();
}



var Measurement = function(line)
{   
    this.msrmntValue = ko.computed(function(){
            var a = 20*line.convertFactor();
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "\nValue set to " + a;
            return a;
        });
}

var line = new Line();
line.convertFactor(20);

var msrmnt1 = new Measurement(line);
var msrmnt2 = new Measurement(line);

// Display the value 
function SetValue()
{
    line.convertFactor(40);
};

function NullifyAndSetValue()
{
    msrmnt1 = null;
    msrmnt2 = null;
    // After the ibjects have been nullified I want that the computed properties should not be recalculated
    // and the objects should be garbage collected, but looks like the objects are left in memory indefinitely 
    // because knockout is still referenceing them.
    line.convertFactor(80);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `dispose` method of the `ko.computed`.

From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-reference.html#using-a-computed-observable):

> `dispose()` — Manually disposes the computed observable, clearing all subscriptions to dependencies. This function is useful if you want to stop a computed observable from being updated **or want to clean up memory for a computed observable that has dependencies on observables that won’t be cleaned.**

So you just need to write:

```
function NullifyAndSetValue()
{
    msrmnt1.msrmntValue.dispose();
    msrmnt1 = null;

    msrmnt2.msrmntValue.dispose();
    msrmnt2 = null;

    line.convertFactor(80);
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcmLvht3/1/).

Comment: Thanks @nemsev. Just a trivial change in the fiddle that you provided - we need to dispose the computed properties before nullifying the object..